# I need my code to find the average of all the scores and print it out in a dialog box

Tags: java

I am having problems trying to get the average of the scores. Could you please help me fix this code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class ProgrammingExercise6b{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  String input = "";
  int score = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int sum = 0;

  do {
   count++;
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the grades:");
   score = Integer.parseInt(input);

   if (score == -1) {
    sum += score;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average is: " + (score / count));
    break;
   } else {
    continue;
   }


  } while (true);
 } //main
}
```

I need help to understand how to add up all the numbers and divide them by the number of numbers to get the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `sum += score;` and `count++` in else part, before `continue;` line. Also use sum in calculation final result. Your updated code should look like below

```
    String input;
    int score ;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    do {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the grades:");
        score = Integer.parseInt(input);

        if (score == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average is: " + (sum / count));
            break;
        } else {
            sum += score;
            count++;
            continue;
        }
    } while (true);
```

Comment: this is still giving me 0 as the average upon typing 50 50 50 and 45.

Comment: I added full code in my answer. Please check if it works for you could you please mark it as approved?

Answer (score 0):

for the scores you should store them in an ArrayList `List<Integer> scoresList= new ArrayList<Integer>();`

To add to the arrayList you use

```
scoresList.add(yourScore);
```

have a seperate integer "scoresSum" which is the sum of your scores.
To get the sum you iterate through the list. something like this

```
    for(int score: scoresList)
{
   scoresSum += score;
}
```

finally have a variable average which equals the average

```
int average = scoresSum/scoresList.size();
```

also since you want to check the score isn't -1. add the score to the ArrayList after you check that the value is not equal -1

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like a homework assignment, I would first and foremost recommend brushing up on your math. You need to understand how an average is calculated before you can write any code.

**For example** in order to calculate the Average it will be the sum divided by the total count and logically you should only increment count when the sum is updated (score is added).

Hope that points you in the right direction. You must understand how to solve the problem before you correctly code a solution.